# How to produce result based on date with multiple conditions on power bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm trying to create validation based on date and some filters

my input table is

```
Status  Type    Date        PolicyNo 
PS      T607    01-01-2020  1002
PS      T608    01-01-2020  1002
CF      T646    01-01-2020  1002
PS      T607    04-01-2020  1003
```

My condition is

1) In a single day how to apply multiple conditions

- Ex. 01-01-2020 on day 1002 Policy(1002) we have three Type T607 with any one of (T608/T646) with status (PS/CF) the output value could be 0 otherwise 1

2) My expected output is

```
Status  Type    Date        PolicyNo    Accept
PS      T607    01-01-2020  1002        0
PS      T608    01-01-2020  1002        0
CF      T646    01-01-2020  1002        0
PS      T607    04-01-2020  1003        1
```

**EDIT:**

```
Date
01-01-2020
01-01-2020
01-01-2020

PolicyNo
1002
1002
1002

Type : T697 with (T608 or T646)

T607 - compalsory so (&&)
T608 - Optional so (||)
T646 - Optional so 

(and)

Status : PS or CF 
PS - Optional so (||)
CF - Optional
```

**Conclude Condition:** Same date (ex.01-01-2020) and Same PolicyNo(ex.1002) with (Type: T697 with (T608 or T646)) with (Status: PS or CF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple conditions in M (Power Query) for a custom column:

```
= if [Date] = Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()) and [Type] = "T607" and [PolicyNo] = 1003 then 1 else 0
```

And so on...

Note: The syntax has to be lower case, becaue M is case sensitive.
You also can stack the if´s or use else if´s. You can also use a `or` condition.

You can do the same in DAX thou. With `IF()` and `OR()` functions (as new column):

```
= IF(OR([Date] = TODAY(), [Type] = "T607", [PolicyNo] = 1003), 1, 0)
```

**EDIT**

To your 4th comment. This logik works just fine (simplified sample):

[image]

Comment: I'm working with dynamic data. Date and PolicyNo are dynamic,  Type T697 with any one of (T608/T646) with status (PS/CF) this condition is static.

Comment: ```WITCH(TRUE(),'DatewithOtherConditions'[type] = "T607" && 'DatewithOtherConditions'[type] = "T608" || 'DatewithOtherConditions'[type] = "T646" && 'DatewithOtherConditions'[status] = "CF" || 'DatewithOtherConditions'[status] = "CF"   && DatewithOtherConditions[Date] ,0,1)``` i'm writing this code getting wrong result.

Comment: What i'm expecting is ```((Value1 && (Value2 || Value3)) && (Value4 || Value5))``` depends on PolicyNo and Running Dates.

Comment: ```if (([Type] = "T607" and ([Type] = "T608" or [Type] = "T646")) and ([Status] = "PS" or [Status] = "CF")) then 0 else 1``` also not working producing wrong result. The condition is Date and PolicyNo. Same day with same PolicyNo the above condition should satisfy

Comment: Your question and comments are to confusing^^ Based on that I have no clue how your final condition should look like. You can try to post your final condition in steps or in a simpliefied way. Like that maybe: `(Value=1 && (Value = 2 || Value2 = 3)) and Date = PolicyNo`